# How do i query properly to get the statistical data I need with current data format? (mongoDB / NoSQL)

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have been struggling to find a way to get the statistical data that I need to share with other department.

this is a current document example in MongoDB.

```
{
date : ‘2021-09-10T12:00:00+09:00’,
Category : ‘usedCar’,
Data : [
    {name : ‘bmw’, theNumberOfSold : 15},
    {name : ‘Honda’, theNumberOfSold : 35},
    {name : ‘Toyota’, theNumberOfSold : 100}…….
] 
}

{
date : ‘2021-09-11T12:00:00+09:00’,
Category : ‘newCar’,
Data : [
    {name : ‘bmw’, theNumberOfSold : 5},
    {name : ‘Honda’, theNumberOfSold : 8},
    {name : ‘Toyota’, theNumberOfSold : 150}…….
] 
}
```

I'd like to get the result as follows. Would it be possible by mongodb aggregate query? I've tried so many ways the whole day but wouldn't get any..

-2021 Sep, usedCar list by name sorted by theNumberOfSold
-2021 Jan~July, newCar list by name sorted by theNumberOfSold

[the way I am going to utilize extracted data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJH1L.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `$unwind` unwind data
- `$group` group by month、year、name

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$Data"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        year: {
          "$year": "$date"
        },
        month: {
          "$month": "$date"
        },
        name: "$Data.name"
      },
      totalAmount: {
        $sum: "$Data.theNumberOfSold"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jGBh6hYYvpr)

Comment: Thank you so much! it's very helpful!